How to set size resolution
I have developed an application using Codename One. The application only uses the paint method to draw objects. The problem I encounter is that when I run it as a desktop app, the image displays correctly, but when I run it in a vertical simulator, the image is shrunk.


public class Main extends Lifecycle {

    public static GameCanvas gameCanvas;

    @Override
    public void runApp() {
        gameCanvas = new GameCanvas();
        gameCanvas.start();
        gameCanvas.show();
    }
}

public final class GameCanvas extends Form{
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics var1) {
        try {
           var1.drawImage(imgLogo, this.getWidth() >> 1,this.getHeight() >> 1);
        } catch (Exception var3) {
        }
    }
}


I would need to see the code to tell you what's wrong... I'm guessing you don't adapt to the device size but without the code it's pure speculation.

@ShaiAlmog I simply drew the logo, but it became smaller when viewed in the vertical simulator

I suggest reading the "density" section of the developer guide. An image with 500 pixels might look big on a desktop and small on a mobile device. Also if you added the images as multi-images you might be getting a different result from your expectations. You should read about that too.
